# One to many relationship, configure which field is referenced in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here are the domains:

```
public class Person : Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    pucli ICollection<PersonChild> Children
}

public class PersonChild
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public Person Child { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my configuration:

```
HasRequired(p => p.Person).WithMany().HasForeignKey(pc => pc.PersonId);
```

My question is how can I configure the Children property of Person to reference on PersonIds in PersonChild? My current configuration keeps on referencing to ChildIds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem is to specify which field is referenced in configuration:

```
HasRequired(pc => pc.Person).WithMany(p => p.Children).HasForeignKey(pc => pc.PersonId);
```